# Determinar si la letra ingresada es vocal

Tags: c, variables

¿Cómo guardaría letras a una variable?, no sé como se haría correctamente
para decir si la letra ingresada es vocal o no

```
void pedir_vocal(){
    char vocal[]={'A', 'E', 'I' ,'O', 'U'}; 
    char letra; 

    printf("Ingrese una vocal");
    scanf("%s", letra);

    while (letra != vocal ){
        printf("Ingrese una vocal correcta");
        scanf ("%s", letra);
    }

    printf("La vocal ingresada es: %s", letra); 
}
```

Comment: Tienes dos formas de hacerlo. Una de ellas es comprobando uno a uno el contenido de la matriz `vocal` y la otra es mediante el uso de una cadena de caracteres y la función de búsqueda de un carácter en una cadena [`strchr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/).

Answer (score 3):

> No sé como se haría correctamente para decir si la letra ingresada es vocal o no.

La pregunta es mucho más compleja de lo que estás mostrando en tu código. A priori no has tenido en cuenta las minúsculas, así que tu formación de vocales debería ser:

```
char vocal[]={'A', 'E', 'I' ,'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
```

Pero tampoco has contado las vocales con variaciones:

```
char vocal[]={
               'A', 'E', 'I' ,'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u',
               'Á', 'É', 'Í' ,'Ó', 'Ú', 'á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú',
               'À', 'È', 'Ì' ,'Ò', 'Ù', 'à', 'è', 'ì', 'ò', 'ù',
               'Ä', 'Ë', 'Ï' ,'Ö', 'Ü', 'ä', 'ë', 'ï', 'ö', 'ü',
               'Â', 'Ê', 'Î' ,'Ô', 'Û', 'â', 'ê', 'î', 'ô', 'û'
             };
```

Y si tienes en cuenta más escrituras (Griego, Cirílico) el problema crece exponencialmente. Vamos a asumir que quieres ver si el carácter es una vocal, de alfabeto español, sin variantes. La forma más eficiente de hacerlo es mediante un `switch`:

```
int main(void) {

    char letra = 0; 

    printf("Ingrese una vocal: ");
    scanf_s("%c", &letra);

    while (1) {
        switch (letra) {
            case 'a': case 'A':
            case 'e': case 'E':
            case 'i': case 'I':
            case 'o': case 'O':
            case 'u': case 'U':
                printf("La vocal ingresada es: %s", letra);
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Ingrese una vocal correcta");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Al apartado de mayúsculas, por qué no poner un toupper()? siempre es recomendable cuando se trata de strings añadir toupper a la entrada de texto y a la variable para que si o si, se compare siempre todo en mayúsculas o en minusculas tolower()

Comment: Tu propuesta es correcta, pero he elegido la opción que menos haga trabajar a la CPU, un `switch` es muy económico a nivel de proceso y genera código muy compacto, si además me ahorro una llamada a función el código es aún más compacto. Puedes ver las diferencias en [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/C3aPQL).

Comment: Mi +1, pero hay que tener cuidado con los caracteres multibyte o te generarán el típico `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion` o `warning: multi-character character constant`. Compilar compila, pero trunca cada carácter al byte menos significativo.

Comment: No he usado ni un literal multicaracter O_O respecto a caracteres multibyte… eso es un campo de minas, por eso lo he acabado evitando en la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Como te han dicho @OscarGarcia en comentarios, puedes usar la función strchr que busca un caracter en una cadena, o también recorrer la cadena caracter a caracter comparando con el que has introducido por teclado hasta encontrar coincidencia. Si llegas al final de la cadena que contiene las vocales y no hay coincidencia, no es una vocal. Usando la función strchr sería algo como esto:

```
int main(void){

    char vocal[]= "AEIOUaeiou"; 
    char letra = 0; 

    printf("Ingrese una vocal: ");
    scanf_s("%c", &letra);

    while ( strchr( vocal, letra ) == NULL){
        printf("Ingrese una vocal correcta: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf_s ("%c", &letra);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Para empezar he añadido las vocales minúsculas (no se si es necesario en tu caso), y he definido la cadena de forma fácil, en vez de poner cada caracter de uno en uno.

También he añadido el operador `&` delante de la variable letra porque la función scanf necesita la dirección de memoria de la variable en la que guardará lo tecleado.

Ya de paso, como el compilador me ha dado un warning por usar scanf en vez de la versión segura scanf_s, también he cambiado la función utilizada.

Y para terminar, he añadido el fflush del stdin para eliminar el salto de línea que se queda cada vez que introduces una letra y pulsas ENTER. Si no haces esto, el segundo scanf_s retornaría el ENTER anterior y no te pediría que pulsaras ninguna tecla.

Espero que te sirva.